# Unable to make screenshot due to javascript logs in Phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

We are trying to generate screenshot for this following site for Final Product Page, but getting Error messages in console due to JavaScript Errors on site and cannot generate more than 1-screenshot.

Link : http://shop.reebok.com/us/product/Men-DMXSky-Impact-Shoes/NV326?cid=V61752

**Log :**
[image]

**CODE[Without Error Handle] :**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://shop.reebok.com/us/product/Men-DMXSky-Impact-Shoes/NV326?cid=V61752', function () {
window.setTimeout(function () {
page.render('output.jpg');
phantom.exit();
});
});
```

Error messages are logged and screenshots are not generated.

**CODE[With Error Handle] :**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {

var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];

  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
    });
  }
  //console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};

page.open('http://shop.reebok.com/us/product/Men-DMXSky-Impact-Shoes/NV326?cid=V61752', function () {
window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('output.jpg');
            phantom.exit();
});
});
```

This doesn't logs error messages in console, but still Screenshot is not created.

Reference from :
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html

Answer (score 0):

Many of the problems concerning screenshots are because page.render is called too early when rendering the page. It's recommanded to wait a little more once the callback is invoked.

When using setTimeout, please provide a duration like this

```
page.open('http://shop.reebok.com/us/product/Men-DMXSky-Impact-Shoes/NV326?cid=V61752', function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render('output.jpg');
                phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);
});
```

On the other side, you're true : a js error on the page could prevent capture to work correctly ; so you have to add an error handler to `page.onerror` or to `phantom.onerror`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried your solution, but didn't worked. Finally I have disabled js and now it is working fine.